# Sending html email to bat! program (C#)

Tags: html, html-email, imagemap

I`m trying to send an HTML email, which will be received via Bat! program.

Mail is being sent from C# code.
I set up `IsBodyHtml = true;`.
My HTML code is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mail</title>

</head>
<body> 
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="20,29,303,155" href="http://mysite.com" alt="this is my site" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="372,23,479,103" href="http://somesite.com/" alt="somesite" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="35,345,169,408" href="anotherlink.com" alt="" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="178,348,332,409" href="http://www.lastsite.com/" alt="lastsite" />
</map>
<img src="cid:mail" usemap ="#planetmap" border="0"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This mail is displayed in Outlook well but in Bat! it is only an image (map is not working).
Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Email clients restrict what HTML they support. This is for a vareity of reasons, including security.

I would suggest slicing your image up and use Tables, or simply directing users to a webpage with the image map if it's a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [features](http://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/thebat/features.php) page,

> The Bat! benefits of its own HTML viewing mechanism – Robin HTML Viewer, as well as of its own image viewing module.

HTML Email is generally a nightmare, and is one situation where it is recommended to use tables for layout, for example. You have discovered that image maps will not work in The Bat!, so you should redesign the layout to only require simple image links.